# Data copied between rows on form's datagrid

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

Within AX 2009, I have, through compare and compile, added two new controls within a datagrid on a form, a Real edit and a combobox. I have compiled with no issues. The Allow Edit property is set to Yes on both controls.

However, on the form, if I edit one row, whether typing a new number with Real edit or combobox, and don't hit Save but hit the Down Arrow key, the data I typed on the previous records is duplicate in the next record and so on until I release the Down Arrow key, rather than just setting the focus on a new record.

The table where these fields were created doesn't exhibit this behavior. The focus simply moves to the next record and what was typed will not carry over to the next record. Only the form does this...

Has anyone seen this behavior before with AX forms?

Comment: Are the fields standard or display/edit methods?

Comment: The fields are definitely standard versus using display/edit methods. I did resolved the Down Arrow behavior by going to the modified form, and removing the datasource/field combination on both of the controls' properties. Then I placed the same ones back and recompiled. Now it functions as normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have omitted to specify the data source on the grid itself?

Or if the new controls are based on Edit methods on the data source, have you got the data source parameter in the method signature?

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa637541(AX.10).aspx

Comment: These are definitely standard fields. I resolved that behavior by going to the form, removing the datasource/field proerpties on both controls, and placing it back. I recompiled and it worked. Thanks for looking into this.